# Function returning None in Python

Tags: python, function

Below code is printing None, but should be printing a value

```
num_ex = 3.5

def my_func(x):
    if x >= 3.00:
        x - 1
    else:
        x + 1

var_ex = my_func(num_ex)
print(var_ex)
```

Comment: How could it possibly return a value, when it has no `return` statement in it?

Comment: sorry, i meant printing, edited

Comment: @JackW24 he means that your function definition needs to have `return x` at the end, in order for `my_func(num_ex)` to return to some value to assign `var_ex`. Current it has no return statement, so `my_funct()` evaluates to `None` which makes the expression evaluate to `var_ex = None`

Answer (score 2):

Every Python user define function return **None** by default. You are not returning anything that's why it's returning **None**

To return a value from a function you use the **return** keyword.

**Note:** the **return** keyword terminates the function immediately when encounter.

**For Example**

```py
num_ex = 3.5

def my_func(x):
    if x >= 3.00:
       return x - 1
    return x + 1

var_ex = my_func(num_ex)
print(var_ex)
```